# Jsoup - Select an element with child X

Tags: jsoup

I'd like to use Jsoup to select an element with a child that matches selector X.  However, I don't want the child: I want the *parent* containing it.

For example, given `<p><img src="1"/></p><p><img src="2"/></p>"`, I'd like to be able to do something like `"p:with-child(img[src=2])"` to select `"<p><img src="2"/></p>"`

Comment: It's already in docs - http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation Specify your selector for specific child and then you can use `parent()` method to grab its parent.

Comment: But I don't know how far down it is - it may be a grandchild or greatgreatgrandchild - so I don't know how to call parent.

Comment: Ok, got your point. Please check if provided answer resolves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may try with with:

```
document.select("p:has(img[src=2])")
```

which will return all `p` elements that contain `<img src="2" />` elements in one of the children nodes. It might be the first level child or n-level one if nested in some other html elements.

Another approach is to use `parents()` method which will return a list of parents in a tree-like order. But then you will have to traverse this list and find a parent you are interested in.